# What were the last word of Lord Buddha according to different schools of Buddhism?

Tags: the-buddha

I am a Theravada Buddhist.i am curious to know about Lord Buddha's Last words according to different schools of Buddhism.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Buddha expressed the Dharmaparyaya of the True Law (the Lotus Sutra) before becoming completely exctinct. Best regards.

Comment: Welcome to Buddhism SE!  Yvain. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> *handa'dāni bhikkhave āmantayāmi vo, vayadhammā sankhārā appamādena sampādethā ti.*
>
> Disciples, this I declare to you: All conditioned things are subject to disintegration - strive on untiringly for your liberation. (Mahāparinibbāna Sutta)

The Buddha in the Mahaparinibbana Sutta ([Digha Nikaya Sutta 16](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.16.1-6.vaji.html)) advised the monks assembled around his death bed that they should take the Dhamma-Vinaya as their teacher after his passing- or, in brief, the Dhamma is the TEACHER of every Buddhist. We  are all disciples, be it monks or Upasaka, Upasika…

Also in this Sutta he said that…

> without approval and without scorn, but carefully studying the sentences word by word, one should trace whatever is said as ‘Dhamma’,  in the Discourses and verify them by the Discipline. If they are neither traceable in the Discourses nor verifiable by the Discipline, one must conclude thus: ‘Certainly, this is not the Blessed One’s utterance; this has been misunderstood by that bhikkhu — or by that community, or by those elders, or by that elder.’ In that way, bhikkhus, you should reject it.

As per the Sutta, there are four points by which one can know of oneself that one is a sotapanna:

- “Buddhe aveccappasādena samannāgato hoti” - one is endowed with unshakable confidence in the Buddha;
- “Dhamme aveccappasādena samannāgato hoti” - one is endowed with unshakable confidence in the Dhamma;
- “Sanghe aveccappasādena samannāgato hoti” - one is endowed with unshakable confidence in the Sangha;
- “Ariyakantehi sīlehi samannāgato hoti”- one is endowed with the moral precepts cherished by the noble ones, i.e. the five precepts.

Thus in the Mahaparinibbana Sutta, the Supreme Buddha says…

> "This, Ananda, is the teaching called the Mirror of the Dhamma, whereby the noble disciple may thus know of himself: 'There is no more rebirth for me in hell, nor as an animal or ghost, nor in any realm of woe. A stream-enterer am I, safe from falling into the states of misery, assured am I and bound for Enlightenment.”